# Please tell me where I've gone wrong

Tags: c, debugging

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char name1[15],name2[15],name3[15];
    int no;

    printf("Enter the serial number and name one\n");
    scanf("%d %15c',&no, name1");
    printf("%d %15s\n\n",no,name1);

    printf("Enter serial number and name two\n");
    scanf("%d %s",&no,name2);
    printf("%d %15s\n\n",no, name2);

    printf("Enter serial number and name three");
    scanf("%d %15s",&no,name3);
    printf("%d %15s\n\n",no,name3);
}
```

Hi, I'm new to programming, I've started with C for some reasons. The code I've typed above is my program that I want to execute. When I execute it with Code::Blocks it runs till *Enter the serial number and name one* and then if I enter a number it become not responding. Then I tried compiling using Visual Studio 2013 it again stops responding.

After that I tried debugging using Visual Studio 2013 debugger it said this *First-chance exception at 0x7575B790 (msvcrt.dll) in temp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.* after pressing continue it said this *Unhandled exception at 0x7575B790 (msvcrt.dll) in temp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.* 
I have programmed before this one in Code::Blocks they all worked well. Please tell me where I've gone wrong. Also please explain the use of %s.

Thanks

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). While you're at it, find the documentation for `printf` and `scanf`. If you don't understand how they work, you probably won't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so stupid. Thanks btw :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scanf("%d %15c',&no, name1");
```

Should be replaced with:

```
scanf("%d %14s",&no, name1);
```

- Use double quotes since the single quote doesn't terminate a String in C.
- Use `%14s` (as suggested by chux) so that you do not overflow the buffer for the string and cause a seg fault

`%s` is used to read in a space delimited string. If you want to read an entire line, you must make use of [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) function

Comment: And just to reiterate chux's point. Note that chux wrote __14__ not __15__. This will ensure that scanf won't cause a buffer overflow when adding the null terminating character.